# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000058 (code=1), thread 8100

Tags: java, android

i have develop game but after some time application was crashed and restart. when application crashed it show the message fatal signal 11 error.

Main Activity

Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000058 (code=1), thread 8100 (l_jacksorbetter)

```
package com.vs.final_jacksorbetter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Game g;
private Player p;
private int tempbet;
private String[] cards;
private Boolean secondTurn, hasStarted;
private Context context;
private TextView credtext,bettext,txtHold1,txtHold2,txtHold3,txtHold4,txtHold5,txtRank;
TextView tvJ,tvTP,tvTK,tvS,tvF,tvFH,tvFK,tvSF,tvRF;
boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
int i,x,y,creditstr2,result;
private Button betb,betMax,btnDouble;
LinearLayout ll1,ll2,ll3,ll4,ll5;
String creditStr,creditStr1;
static String val;
Animation animation;
MediaPlayer mp,mp1,mp2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    tempbet = 0;
    secondTurn = false;
    hasStarted = false;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);


    animation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
    animation.setDuration(700); 
    animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()); 
    animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE); 
    animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);

    SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences("MySharedPref", MODE_PRIVATE );
    val = (sp.getString("Credit", "500"));
    p = new Player();

    tvJ = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView91);
    tvTP = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView81);
    tvTK = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView71);
    tvS = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView61);
    tvF = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView51);
    tvFH = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView41);
    tvFK = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView31);
    tvSF = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView21);
    tvRF = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    txtHold1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_Hold1);
    txtHold2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_Hold2);
    txtHold3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_Hold3);
    txtHold4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_Hold4);
    txtHold5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_Hold5);
    txtRank = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtRank);

    ll1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll02);
    ll2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll03);
    ll3 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll04);
    ll4 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll05);
    ll5 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll06);

    context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "Place your bet, touch the deck to start";
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();

    credtext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.creditstextview);
    credtext.setText("Credits: "+(CharSequence)(""+p.getCredits()));

    //----------------------------------Button Achievement----------------------------
    Button btnAchieve = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_Achievement);
    btnAchieve.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AchievementsActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });

    //----------------------------------Button Deal------------------------------------
    //mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beep);
   // mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.deal);
    //mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hold);

    final Button btn_Click = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_Deal);
    btn_Click.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(btn_Click.getText().toString().equals("DEAL")) {
                btn_Click.setText("DRAW");
            }
            else if(btn_Click.getText().toString().equals("DRAW")) {
                btn_Click.setText("DEAL");
            }
            if(!secondTurn)
                startGame();
            else

                finalTurn();
                secondTurn=!secondTurn;
        }
    });
    for(int i=1;i<6;i++) {
        final int tvar = i-1;
        ImageView timv = (ImageView) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("card"+i, "id", getPackageName()));
        timv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(secondTurn && hasStarted)
                holdCard((ImageView)v, tvar);
            }
        });
    }

    //-----------------------------------Double Up-------------------------------------
    btnDouble = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_DoubleUp);
    btnDouble.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(btnDouble.getText().toString().equals("DOUBLE ON")) {
                btnDouble.setText("DOUBLE OFF");
            }
            else if(btnDouble.getText().toString().equals("DOUBLE OFF")) {
                btnDouble.setText("DOUBLE ON");
            }
        }
    });

    //-----------------------------------Bet Max---------------------------------------
    betMax = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_BetMax);
    betMax.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(tempbet+1<6 &tempbet<p.getCredits()) {
                tempbet=5;
                bettext.setText("Bet: "+(CharSequence)(""+tempbet));
                if(tempbet==5) {
                    ll5.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FE2E2E"));
                    ll1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00"));
                    ll2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00"));
                    ll3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00"));
                    ll4.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00"));
                }
            }
            else {
                v.setEnabled(false);
            }
            if(betMax.isClickable()) {
                betb.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else {
                betb.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    });

    //-------------------------------------------Bet Button------------------------------ 
    bettext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtBet);
    betb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Bet);
    betb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
          //mp.start();
        if(tempbet+1<6 &tempbet<p.getCredits()) {
            tempbet++;
            bettext.setText("Bet: "+(CharSequence)(""+tempbet));
            if(tempbet==1) {
                ll1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FE2E2E"));
                ll2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00"));
                ll3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00"));
                ll4.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00"));
                ll5.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00"));
            }
            if(tempbet==2) {
                ll2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FE2E2E"));
                ll1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00"));
                ll3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00"));
                ll4.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00"));
                ll5.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00"));
            }
            if(tempbet==3) {
                ll3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FE2E2E"));
                ll1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00"));
                ll2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00"));
                ll4.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00"));
                ll5.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00"));
            }
            if(tempbet==4) {
                ll4.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FE2E2E"));
                ll1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00"));
                ll2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00"));
                ll3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00"));
                ll5.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00"));
            }
            if(tempbet==5) {
                ll5.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FE2E2E"));
                ll1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00"));
                ll2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00"));
                ll3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00"));
                ll4.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00"));
            }
        }
        else
            v.setEnabled(false);
      }
    });
}

//---------------------------------Start Game---------------------------------
private void startGame() {
    tvJ.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Black));
    tvTP.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Black));
    tvTK.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Black));
    tvS.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Black));
    tvF.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Black));
    tvFH.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Black));
    tvFK.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Black));
    tvSF.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Black));
    tvRF.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Black));
    hasStarted=true;
    if(tempbet==0)
        tempbet=1;
    g = new Game(p, tempbet);
    betb.setEnabled(false);
    betMax.setEnabled(false);
    btnDouble.setEnabled(false);
    p.setCredits(-g.bet);
    credtext.setText("Credits: "+(CharSequence)(""+p.getCredits()));
    y = p.getCredits();
    creditStr1 = String.valueOf(y);
    bettext.setText("Bet: "+(CharSequence)(""+g.bet));
    if(tempbet==1) {
        ll1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FE2E2E"));
        ll2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00"));
        ll3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00"));
        ll4.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00"));
        ll5.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00"));
    }
    cards = g.getCards();
    for(int i=1;i<6;i++) {
        ImageView card = (ImageView) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("card"+i, "id", getPackageName()));
        card.setImageResource(g.t.cntable.get(cards[i-1]));
        //mp1.start();
    }
    if(g.getRank().contentEquals("No Value"))
        txtRank.setText("");
    else
        txtRank.setText(g.getRank());
}

//----------------------------------Final Round----------------------------------
private void finalTurn() {
    g.dealCards();
    cards = g.getCards();
    g.showdown();
    g.score();
    if(btnDouble.getText().toString().equals("DOUBLE OFF"))
        credtext.setText("Credits: "+(CharSequence)(""+p.getCredits()));
    else
        credtext.setText("Credits: "+(CharSequence)(""+creditStr1));
    x = p.getCredits();
    creditStr = String.valueOf(x);
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "credit: "+creditStr.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    creditstr2 = x-y;

    for(i=1;i<6;i++) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 //TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ImageView card = (ImageView) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("card"+i, "id", getPackageName()));
                card.setImageResource(g.t.cntable.get(cards[i-1]));
                //mp1.start();
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) card.getLayoutParams();
                lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
                card.getDrawable().setColorFilter(null);
            }
        });
                txtHold1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                txtHold2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                txtHold3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                txtHold4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                txtHold5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                ll1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00"));
                ll2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00"));
                ll3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00"));
                ll4.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00"));
                ll5.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00"));
    }
    SharedPreferences sp = MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("MySharedPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor = sp.edit();
    spEditor.putString("Credit", creditStr.toString());
    spEditor.commit();  
    txtRank.startAnimation(animation);
        if(g.getRank().contentEquals("No Value"))
            txtRank.setText("Game Over");
        else
        txtRank.setText(g.getRank());
            if(g.getRank().contentEquals("Jacks or Better"))
            {
                tvJ.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Red));
            }
            else if(g.getRank().contentEquals("Two Pair"))
            {
                tvTP.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Red));
            }
            else if(g.getRank().contentEquals("Three of a Kind"))
            {
                tvTK.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Red));
            }
            else if(g.getRank().contentEquals("Straight"))
            {
                tvS.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Red));
            }
            else if(g.getRank().contentEquals("Flush"))
            {
                tvF.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Red));
            }
            else if(g.getRank().contentEquals("Full House"))
            {
                tvFH.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Red));
            }
            else if(g.getRank().contentEquals("Four of a Kind"))
            {
                tvFK.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Red));
            }
            else if(g.getRank().contentEquals("Straight Flush"))
            {
                tvSF.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Red));
            }
            else if(g.getRank().contentEquals("Royal Flush"))
            {
                tvRF.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Red));
            }
    if(btnDouble.getText().toString().equals("DOUBLE ON")) {
    if((g.getRank().contentEquals("Jacks or Better"))||(g.getRank().contentEquals("Two Pair"))||(g.getRank().contentEquals("Three of a Kind"))
        ||(g.getRank().contentEquals("Straight"))||(g.getRank().contentEquals("Flush"))||(g.getRank().contentEquals("Full House"))
        ||(g.getRank().contentEquals("Four of a Kind"))||(g.getRank().contentEquals("Straight Flush"))||(g.getRank().contentEquals("Royal Flush")))
    {
        Intent intentBack = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DoubleUp_Confirm_Activity.class);
        intentBack.putExtra("IntentType", "Credit");
        intentBack.putExtra("Credits",creditStr1);
        intentBack.putExtra("win", creditstr2);
        intentBack.putExtra("array", cards);
        startActivity(intentBack);
    }}
    g.bet=0;
    tempbet=0;
    bettext.setText("Bet: "+(CharSequence)(""+g.bet));

    betb.setEnabled(true);
    betMax.setEnabled(true);
    btnDouble.setEnabled(true);
}

//------------------------------Hold Cards-----------------------------------------
private void holdCard(ImageView v, int i) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
    Card thiscard = g.getSingleCard(i);
    if(thiscard.isHeld()==false) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.card1:
            //mp2.start();
            lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            v.getDrawable().setColorFilter(0xEC0CF581, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY );
            txtHold1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txtHold1.setText("Held");
            break;
        case R.id.card2:
            //mp2.start();
            lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            v.getDrawable().setColorFilter(0xEC0CF581, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY );
            txtHold2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txtHold2.setText("Held");
            break;
        case R.id.card3:
            //mp2.start();
            lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            v.getDrawable().setColorFilter(0xEC0CF581, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY );
            txtHold3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txtHold3.setText("Held");
            break;
        case R.id.card4:
            //mp2.start();
            lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            v.getDrawable().setColorFilter(0xEC0CF581, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY );
            txtHold4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txtHold4.setText("Held");
            break;
        case R.id.card5:
            //mp2.start();
            lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            v.getDrawable().setColorFilter(0xEC0CF581, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY );
            txtHold5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txtHold5.setText("Held");
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    else {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.card1:
            lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            v.getDrawable().setColorFilter(null);
            txtHold1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            break;
        case R.id.card2:
            lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            v.getDrawable().setColorFilter(null);
            txtHold2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            break;
        case R.id.card3:
            lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            v.getDrawable().setColorFilter(null);
            txtHold3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            break;
        case R.id.card4:
            lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            v.getDrawable().setColorFilter(null);
            txtHold4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            break;
        case R.id.card5:
            lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            v.getDrawable().setColorFilter(null);
            txtHold5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    thiscard.Held();
    v.setLayoutParams(lp);
}



//----------------------------------------Double click to Exit---------------------------------------------

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(secondTurn) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please Complete this hand", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }
        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: i don't know where to create error please help me.

Comment: what you have tried yet ?

Comment: when i run my app it crashed after some time i think when set image resource some error occurred. but lower version phone it work properly.

Comment: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 3267016-byte allocation  
  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)  
  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:636)
  at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1522) 
  at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:366)
  at com.vs.final_jacksorbetter.MainActivity.startGame(MainActivity.java:270)
  at com.vs.final_jacksorbetter.MainActivity.access$1(MainActivity.java:238)
  at com.vs.final_jacksorbetter.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:123)

Comment: when crashed app that type of error display

Comment: your app is crashing at line 270 of your MainActivity code when you call card.setImageResource.  I think the g.t.cntable.get(cards[i-1]) is causing the issue.

Comment: thank u but how to solve this issue please tell me.

Comment: g,t are java class and cntable is hashmap so what i do set to card other way?

Comment: does it happen every time or in some specific situations

Comment: **Fatal signal 11** is not java error, its linked from Linux VM system, usually associated with problem from device manufacturer

Comment: yes it happen every time but not specific on time, when memory allocated memory full.